# Is there a way to access the Step Function state name inside AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, state-machine

I have a Step Functions statemachine that runs two parallel states. First state calls a Lambda function and second state posts to SNS topic. In case of errors in any of the states, I call a Lambda function to capture the error and notify the team via email.

The challenge here is to get the `Name` of the `State` from which the Lambda function has been invoked.

I tried using context object, but that didn't help. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Step Functions has a context object, which you can send to the execution arn of your Lambda.

See: [Context Object - AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html)